# How to use ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED?

Tags: android, arrays

how to use `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` to monitor the battery state and if it drops under a defined value you can show a custom low-battery-dialogue?
someone give me some example code.
when battery drop to 30% it give custom low-battery-dialogue

Comment: `someone give me some example code` this is not how stackoverflow works. You show us your code, and tell what is a problem, not we write the code instead of you.

Comment: uh....ok sorry for that but i really confused

Comment: why? have you tried searching? There is a tone of examples if you just search

Comment: Take it easy guys he's a newcomer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `BroadcastReceiver` to get what you want :

This is an example of `BroadcastReceiver` class implementation

```
public class BatteryReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //this will give you battery current status

try{
  int level = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0);
  int temp = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, -1);
  int voltage = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, -1);
  int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);

  String BStatus = "No Data";
  if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING){BStatus = "Charging";}
  if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING){BStatus = "Discharging";}
  if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL){BStatus = "Full";}
  if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_NOT_CHARGING){BStatus = "Not Charging";}
  if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_UNKNOWN){BStatus = "Unknown";}

  int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
  String BattPowerSource = "No Data";
  if (chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC){BattPowerSource = "AC";}
  if (chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB){BattPowerSource = "USB";}

  String BattLevel = String.valueOf(level);

  int BHealth = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_HEALTH, -1);
  String BatteryHealth = "No Data";
  if (BHealth == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_COLD){BatteryHealth = "Cold";}
  if (BHealth == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_DEAD){BatteryHealth = "Dead";}
  if (BHealth == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_GOOD){BatteryHealth = "Good";}
  if (BHealth == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_OVER_VOLTAGE){BatteryHealth = "Over-Voltage";}
  if (BHealth == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_OVERHEAT){BatteryHealth = "Overheat";}
  if (BHealth == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_UNKNOWN){BatteryHealth = "Unknown";}
  if (BHealth == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_UNSPECIFIED_FAILURE){BatteryHealth = "Unspecified Failure";}

  //Do whatever with the data here


} catch (Exception e){
    Log.v(TAG, "Battery Info Error");
}
}
};
```

After you create your class , you have to add your `BroadcastReceiver` in your `AndroidManifest`

```
<receiver android:name=".Receiver.BatteryReceiver ">
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED"/>
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

On stackoverflow we share our code and discuss the problems,so all of us can be better.If you're looking for this kind of things you can simply find the docs:

> https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring

Or in the tutorials on the web.